# c++ sorting names alphabetically

Tags: c++, string, sorting

I have a program that is trying to sort some names alphabetically. I run it and it does not have any errors, but the names are not sorted. I compare 2 names and see which one is supposed to be shifted in the array.

Here is the code:

```
void sort_names(char array[])
{
    const int arraysize = 5;

    // Step through each element of the array
    for (int startindex = 0; startindex < arraysize; startindex++)
    {

        int smallestnum = startindex;

        for (int currentindex = startindex + 1; currentindex < arraysize; currentindex++)
        {
            // If the current element is smaller than our previously found smallest
            if ((student_list[currentindex].lname) < (student_list[smallestnum].lname))
            // Store the index 
            smallestnum = currentindex;
        }

        // Swap our start element with our smallest element
        swap(student_list[startindex], student_list[smallestnum]);
    }
}
```

My struct looks like this:

```
struct student {
    char fname[30]; 
    char lname[30];
};
```

Do I have to convert these to strings somewhere because they are characters arrays? I am kind of lost and trying to figure out how to make it sort properly.

Comment: Textual strings are usually best represented by `std::string` in C++. `const char*` is also possible, but `char[]` is not a really a good solution for most cases.

Comment: This looks like homework, if so tag it appropiately please. If not, then move to std::string and std::sort with std::lexicographical_compare.

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::vector`, `std::string`, and `std::sort`?  Your code would then reduce to a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that in this line:

```
if ((student_list[currentindex].lname) < (student_list[smallestnum].lname))
```

it doesn't compare string characters, but rather compares memory adresses.

If you still want to use `char` arrays, you have to use the `strcmp` function. However, I recommed that you use `string` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I used strcmp and it works. I had to use char for the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
if ((student_list[currentindex].lname) < (student_list[smallestnum].lname))
```

The line compares the pointers, it does not compare the contents.

It should be:

```
if ( strcmp( student_list[currentindex].lname, student_list[smallestnum].lname ) < 0 )
```

Another alternative is to use std::string instead, which has built-in comparisons. For example:

```
struct student {
    std::string fname; 
    std::string lname;
};
```